# ¿Qué es lo que ocurre realmente cuando se instancia un objeto en Python?

Tags: python

Hasta ahora lo que ocurre internamente cuando se instancia un objeto, ha sido una caja negra para mí.
Sin embargo hoy me levanté con ganas de responder esta duda: ***¿qué es lo que ocurre cuando instanciamos un objeto a partir de una clase?***.
Es decir, ¿***qué *ruta de métodos* sigue el intérprete cuando hacemos `clase()`***?

Me gustaría poner algunos ejemplos y argumentos; sin embargo, me extendería demasiado y la pregunta en sí misma no cambiaría para nada…

Gracias de antemano…

Comment: Así a bote pronto, lo que viene a mi memoria: `__call__()` de la metaclase (i.e: `type`) ---> `__new__()` de la clase ----> `__init__()` de la clase.

Comment: si, exactamente eso me imaginaba :)

Comment: Siendo estrictos, es el método `__call__()` de la metaclase el que invoca los métodos `__new__()` e `__init__()`, por ese orden, para crear e inicializar la instancia. Ese es el compormiento por defecto de `type`, como base de todas las clases, pero puedes montarte tus metaclases para que tengan otros comportamientos.